# What kind of kippah is this?

Tags: history, clothing, kippa-yarmulka

This photo of my great great grandfather was taken around 1900. He's a Lubavitch Jew from Belarus. His name is Zalman Malkin. He is from Liozna. The story of his life is [here](http://dziga.com/my-name-is-zalman-malkin/).

I was wondering if his kippah indicated a particular region, tradition, or style, or if that was just the general style of kippahs 
during that time period:

[image: Black and white photo of a bearded Jew wearing a tall, round kippah with a flat top.]

Comment: Elliott, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: It seems almost like one of those cool hats that Chazzanim are wearing in pictures of yesteryear, don't you think?

Comment: It is the type of Yarmulkah that Chassidishe Rabbonim wore in that era

Comment: Where can one get such a yarmulke?

Comment: Isn't that the classic käppchen that most Yidden wore before the war?

Comment: pshhhhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 6):

[Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) [wore such a Yarmulke](http://www.havelshouseofhistory.com/Feinstein,%20Rabbi%20Moshe.jpg)

Also [Rabbi Elazar Menachem Man Shach Zatzal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_Shach) [wore such a Yarmulke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aElazar_Shach.jpg)

My understanding is that such a Yarmulke was worn at times when no hat was worn in order to completely cover the head.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be the common lithuanian kippah
http://philippi-collection.blogspot.fr/2011/10/lithuanian-kippah.html

Answer (score 3):

It's the common yarmulka worn by learned men in Lithuania and Belarus, and some other places, at that time. Chassidishe rabbonim, too. Available online here: http://jerusalemyarmulka.com/Product.aspx?CategoryId=10&ProductId=1254